# Look for value then print corresponding cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

This is my test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11oiKLq6EWk9grdrtIKHT0NQ4naTX_tSPl7o8zAQP3Tc/edit?usp=sharing

My core information is in the sheet labeled "Information." In the sheet labeled "Query" I would like to have a formula look at the value in Query!A1 and compare it to Information!A1:A25.

Since Query!A1 matches Information!A2, then Query!B1 and Query!C1 should contain the corresponding information from Information!B2 and Information!C2.

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you need uses the `VLOOKUP` function:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(A1:A,Information!A1:C,{2,3},0)),)
```

Functions used:

- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Please check the answer in [your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11oiKLq6EWk9grdrtIKHT0NQ4naTX_tSPl7o8zAQP3Tc/edit#gid=1165423824&range=B1)

Comment: Works exactly like I wanted! Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please remember that you can also upvote the answer.

Comment: I did up vote the answer, but I haven't reached a high enough level for it to count yet.

Comment: _"....I haven't reached a high enough level"_ **Yes you have**. Have a look at your [privileges scale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: I tried it earlier and it didn't work. I just tried again and it worked. Oh well! It's there now!